# We can't save the invoice right now Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '', query was: INSERT INTO `` () VALUES ()

Tags: magento2, php

Unable to generate invoice in admin order view.
i saw exception log then found this error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '', query was: INSERT INTO `` () VALUES ()
```

anyone have an idea for that

Comment: I have this problem too - did you manage solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and after one day research I got the solution, this error comes because of some table entries are not found in tables - sales_sequence_meta and sales_sequence_profile, after migration, and off course here sales_sequence_meta  represents some tables entries such as 'sequence_order_3', 'sequence_invoice_3', 'sequence_creditmemo_3', 'sequence_shipment_3' etc so if not found create them.

here, number represents store number,

check proper tables and entries as per store number if not found create and the error will be solved.